# error C2064 for Windows but not for Linux

Tags: c++, windows

I am now compiling an open-source image processing project [olena](https://github.com/glazzara/olena). It is a great image processing library and I have succeeded in compiling it for Linux (4.6.3). Since I am used to Windows, I also try to compile the project in Windows with Visual Studio 2010. However, when I compile it, I have the C2064 error message:

```
Error   1   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments    C:\olena-2.1\olena-2.1\milena\mln\metal\is_a.hh 101
```

Following the error message, I come up with this code:

```
 /*!
      \internal
      \brief "is_a" check.

      Check whether T inherits from _CONCEPT_ M.
    */
    template <typename T, template <class> class M>
    struct is_a : bool_<( 
            sizeof( internal::helper_is_a_< T, M >::selector(internal::make_< T >::ptr()) ) //**ERROR**
              ==
              sizeof( internal::yes_ )  )>
    {};
```

It is a very short code snippet, but I have no clue where the error may come from. Any ideas? Thanks.

NOTES:

The definition of `interanl::make_<T>::ptr()` is as follows:

```
  template <typename T>
    inline
    T*
    make_<T>::ptr() // This piece of code is defined to prevent an ICE from g++-2.95.
    {
      T* tmp;
      return tmp;
    }

 template <typename T>
      struct make_
      {
    static T* ptr();
      };
```

The definiton of `iternal::helper_is_a_` is

```
 template <typename T, template <class> class M>
      struct helper_is_a_
      {

    template<class V>
    static yes_ selector(M<V>*);
    static no_  selector(...);
      };
```

Comment: The VS 2010 C++ compiler is quite deficient when it comes to templates. You might want to check with a newer version, where the template support has been greatly improved.

Comment: Please provide a full error message, including the actual `is_a` call being compiled and everything else.

Comment: It is not possible to answer this question without looking at the complete definition of all templates involved: bool_, internal::helper_is_a_ and it's selector() method, apparently.

Comment: <  
internal::helper_is_a_< T, M >::selector(internal::make_< T >::ptr())  >

This looks wrong, as selector should be a type, not a method.

Comment: Can you show the flags being passed to the compiler(s) for both your windows compilation and Linux compilation?

Comment: @0kcats  I have put the definition for helper_is_a in the question

Comment: Post complete code. Don't expect people to assemble it from bits and pieces.

Answer (score 0):

This would work (tested with vs2008).

```
template <typename T, template <class> class M>
struct is_a
{
  static const bool value = bool_<( sizeof( internal::helper_is_a_< T, M >::selector(internal::make_< T >::ptr()) )
        ==
        sizeof( internal::yes_ )  )>::value;
};
```

For whatever reasons it tries to evaluate sizeof immediately when it sees it as a base class or a member.
Your original code compiles with VS2013 C++11.